# How to get .NET to uncommit unused RAM?

Tags: .net, memory, memory-leaks

Here are the stats for my program after it used memory extremely intensively, consuming 6 GB at its peak, but then saving everything to disk and leaving very little in scope:

[image: Screenshot]

Observe that almost everything has gone out of scope *and has been garbage collected* - the heap sizes are tiny. And yet, .NET keeps 181 MB *committed*.

I don't mind the reserved bytes, since that only consumes address space. But the committed memory is annoying – even if it only resides in the page file, it's still quite a lot.

Comment: Try `GC.Collect()`, but don't blame me if your system explodes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [CLR Inside Out - Large Object Heap Uncovered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx) the CLR decommits un-used committed memory during a Gen 2 garbage collection.

This means that you can either wait for a Gen 2 garbage collection to happen on its own or you can force one using `GC.Collect()` - you **really** need to know what you are doing if you choose this route however as it messes with the garbage collectors standard garbage collection cycles which can really mess with performance:

- A full garbage collection is slow so you really don't want to do this too often
- Triggering garbage collections more frequently than the standard schedule will promote additional objects to higher generations meaning they might not be collected as soon as they would normally be

As far as I am aware (from my fairly limited research) the CLR won't release committed memory in other situations.

You should also consider whether or not this is actually a problem:

- If your process is going to immediately go on to perform additional memory-intensive processing then it will need that memory again fairly soon and so there isn't a huge amount of benefit of decommitting that memory anyway
- If you process is done and will terminate shortly then the memory will be decommited anyway
- There isn't necessarily going to be a large disadvantage to having that much memory committed anyway - yes it means that the memory has a backing store allocated, however if the system is under memory pressure then that backing store is likely to be a page file anyway.

**Update:** [Advanced .NET Debugging: Managed Heap and Garbage Collection](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1409801&seqNum=2) appears to back up the hypothesis that memory is only uncommitted during a gen 2 / full collection:

> When objects in generation 2 are collected, the CLR heap manager decommits memory in the segments, and when a segment is no longer needed, it is entirely freed.

Comment: I believe that's true to Large objects heap, not for regular one, right?

Comment: @mikalai I'm not sure - I've not found any references to when the GC decommits memory for the small object heap

Comment: I can't get the application into this weird state again - what I get instead is an app with a couple of GB in Gen 2 (correctly, since they were around for minutes). If I force a Gen 2 GC, that gets cleared and the memory gets uncommitted. I'll keep trying, but for now, a one-off GC.Collect at the end of this long process sounds like the right thing to do.

Comment: @Justin - If I were .net heap, I wouldn't decommit memory. CRT didn't decommit, why .net runtime should? :) Just as an exercise, would be interesting how mono behaves in that sense.

Comment: @mikalai why does it matter what the CRT does? If my app's peak commit was 6 GB, should it stay at 6 GB forever?