# Should i call GC.Collect

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a wcf service hosted as a windows service with the following function:

```cs
public int SendMultipleMessages(List<Message> messages)
{
  foreach (var message in messages)
  {
     //Do some stuff with the messages ie. get an id to return, save info in a db.
  }

  //Would it make sence to collect here ??
  Gc.Collect();

  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //very time demanding task
            _sendRequestHandler.SendMultipleMessages(BatchId);
        });

 return BatchId;
}
```

The List< Message > object (more often than not) uses up to 1 gb of memory, would it make sense to call GC.Collect in a situation like this, since im not using the list anymore, or should i let the Garbage collector handle this on its own ?

Comment: Let GC handle it itself. It knows a lot more than us mere mortals about memory pressure and so forth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it acceptable to call GC.Collect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect)

Comment: Well, considering that list is still in scope, it couldn't be reclaimed at that point anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

If you call `GC.Collect()`, you probably have a problem. It is exceedingly rare to need to call this.

In your current example, **it will not help given the current code**. Unless you physically *clear* the list of `Message` objects, they will not be garbage collected *because the caller still has references* to the objects in that `List<T>` instance.

Of course that advice is based on the assumption that no other references exist to each `Message` object.

You could potentially add some more determinism to your process by removing the message objects from the `List<T>` once they have been processed, or by switching to a data structure which embodies this principle inherently such as a `Queue<T>` or `Stack<T>` depending on your ordering requirements.

```
public int SendMultipleMessages(Queue<Message> messages)
{
  while (messages.Count > 0)
  {
     var message = messages.Dequeue();
     // do something with message, and once you're done it is
     // probably eligible for garbage collection because it is
     // no longer in the Queue
  }

  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //very time demanding task
            _sendRequestHandler.SendMultipleMessages(BatchId);
        });

 return BatchId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the GC manage itself, it will be optimized differently on each machine depending on available resources etc. All you are likely to do by calling it yourself is hurt the performance of your application.

Comment: This answers the title, but not the more specific question.