# Garbage Collection best practice in .net

Tags: c#, .net, oop, garbage-collection

What is the difference between `System.GC.Collect` and `Dispose()`?

Aren't they used for the same purpose, and when should each be used; what is the best practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**System.GC.Collect** is called when all objects which are there in memory are to be collected by the Garbage Collector. Objects which are referenced in managed code are not considered for Garbage collection. This method is used to force the system to reclaim the available memory.

**Dispose()** is not part of GC but as better practice you can use this. It should only be used for objects which uses unmanaged resources like FileStream etc. It should release all the resources that it owns. When you know that certain resources will not be released by GC then you can use the Dispose() method.

The [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

**On a side note:** The GC does not call Dispose, it calls the finalizer(which you should call from Dispose(false))

Also, to make ensure that resources are always released appropriately, a Dispose method should be callable multiple times without throwing an exception.

---

MSDN says:

> **"It is possible to force garbage collection by calling Collect, but
>   most of the time, this should be avoided because it may create
>   performance issues. "**

Check this [blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5afab48c-1ded-433b-a244-fd8d9e66de97/gccollect-dispose-and-destructor):-

> GC.Collect() asks the system to perform a collection "now". You
>   shouldn't mess with this; the system usually has a much better idea
>   than you do of when collection is necessary.

**So is the best practice:**

You can use the **using** block or as you mentioned use the **Dispose** method.

**Why should you use IDisposable and Dispose?**

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx) says

> In many cases it is possible for objects that would otherwise always
>   need to be finalized to avoid that cost by implementing the
>   IDisposable interface. This interface provides an alternative method
>   for reclaiming resources whose lifetime is well known to the
>   programmer, and that actually happens quite a bit. Of course it's
>   better still if your objects simply use only memory and therefore
>   require no finalization or disposing at all; but if finalization is
>   necessary and there are many cases where explicit management of your
>   objects is easy and practical, then implementing the IDisposable
>   interface is a great way to avoid, or at least reduce, finalization
>   costs.

Also check this article on [Improve garbage collector performance using finalize/dispose pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39246/NET-Best-Practice-No-2-Improve-garbage-collector)

Comment: (Almost) Never ever use a destructor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman:- Deleted the Destructor part as I think that was misleading! Does that makes my answer better?

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't my -1.

Comment: @HenkHolterman:- Ok...not an issue Sir. It may be that Destructor misleaded someone else too! :)

Comment: And regarding your comment: that's outdated. When you have an unmanaged resource, wrap it in a `SafeHandle`. No destructor needed.

Answer (score 6):

Best practice is to never need to call `GC.Collect`, and to call `Dispose` on all `IDisposable` objects when you're done with them.

Comment: Or use `using` blocks which are exception-safe.

Comment: Correct but you do not address the fact that GC and IDisposable do __not__  serve the same purpose. The two guidelines are pretty much unrelated.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of **GC.Collect** is to to tell the Garbage collector that there are some objects in the memory that can be collected and it is the right time to collect. Though, as a rule of thumb you should leave that to GC itself. It is designed to do this job.

If there are some resources in your object that you think GC won't take care of. You should implement **Dispose and take care of them yourself**. You need to call Dispose Explicitly to dispose the resources you want. And if you are implementing IDisposable than you can also do that by the **Using** statement.

Comment: Ehsan's advice seems right. I have a case where we iteratively go through a performance critical section, then pause. During the pause, we call GC.Collect in hopes of avoiding the system choosing to collect in the middle of the performance critical section. This seems like one appropriate use case for GC.Collect.