# When to remove GC.Collect

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection

I understand there are a lot of questions talking about when should we use GC.Collect(), but I would like to know how to verify a complicated enterprise program if I realize one of the class has this line that seems to cause performance issue? Are there any good steps to follow and verify this line is safe to remove?

Comment: The question should argubly be _"when to **add** `GC.Collect()`"_

Comment: _"...seems to cause performance issue..."_  - doubt that would be a problem post .NET 4 on workstations and .NET 4.5 on server

Answer (score 2):

> When to remove GC.Collect

Pretty much whenever you see it...

> Are there any good steps to follow

If you can't see any good reason to have it. Good step to follow is just removing it. I can't see it can introduce any NEW issues. Garbage collector has been optimized to call this automatically when ever needed.

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/478177/591656), there can be very rare cases that, this can be useful. But generally, whenever I see this, it gives me a bad impression and concerns...

> verify this line is safe to remove

Sometime people blindly add this when there are memory leak concerns. But this can't help for any memory leaks. So, just use a memory profiling tool and verify that there are no memory leaks. However, just removing this can't introduce any NEW memory leak.