# C# is it possible to create a method for a class that gets run when the object is garbage collected

Tags: c#

Hello I am currently working on a project where I have a class called 'args' this class is used to store function arguments, It stores them as key value pairs, and then has a method called 'Extract' to remove a key value pair from the arguments.

I would like to make it so a warning is added to a warnings file if you provide arguments that go unused in an 'args' object. So I was wondering what would be a good way to do this. One idea I had was to make the class an IDisposable, but do you guys have a better idea?

Comment: _"I would like to make it so a warning is added to a warnings file if you provide arguments that go unused in an 'args' object."_ - I am not sure how that is related to wanting to have a finalizer. My first thought would be to think about how to put this into a Roslyn Analyzer. Not sure though if static analysis can even do this. **If** you are planning to just check if there is a KVP left in the object at the time it becomes eligible for GC, then I'd recommend implementing IDisposable over having a Finalizer. Be aware that this doesn't necessarily mean that the entry is _never_ used, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to define actions that are executed when an object is being garbage collected by implementing a finalizer. A finalizer is a special method that is automatically called by the garbage collector before the object is collected.

Here's how you can implement a finalizer in a C# class:

```
class MyClass
{
    // Finalizer
    ~MyClass()
    {
        // Code to execute when the object is being garbage collected
        Console.WriteLine("Object is being garbage collected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to read the Notes in [Finalizers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers), though and think about what effect that has in your specific context.

Comment: If you're going to write a finalizer, A must read: [When everything you know is wrong](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/) (This is the link for the first part of a two parts blog series by Eric Lippert.

Comment: BTW, the GC doesn't call the finalizer method, [the finalizer thread does.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433270/c-sharp-destructor-vs-idisposable/50433303#comment87967030_50433303)