# Clean up list with objects holding another list

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I was wondering how to clean up a list holding objects containing another list.

Like so :

```
List<Foo> FooCollection = new List<Foo>();

Foo foo1 = new Foo(new List<Bar>());
Foo foo2 = new Foo(new List<Bar>());

FooCollection.Add(foo1);
FooCollection.Add(foo2);
```

Is this enough ?

```
FooCollection = null;
```

Comment: Yes it should. If there is no other references to the collection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends if you want to use `FooCollection` later in code.

```
// reuse the same object
FooCollection.Clear();
// start of with new collection
FooCollection = new List<Foo>();


FooCollection = null;
```

Comment: I don't want to use the list again. Only cleaning it up, so there are no memory leaks.

Comment: Where is `FooCollection` used ? inside a function ? When it exits GC eventually cleans stuff up. You are not playing with unmanaged resources are you ?

Comment: There are no unmanged resources involved. FooCollection is a property of another object, which has a Clear() method. There a set FooCollection = null.

Comment: @Ron if you want to give memory free, of course, you can set FooCollection = null; and then you can call GC.Collect(); (See my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to set the `FooCollection = null`, because using List methods, like `FooCollection.Add()` will throw an exception.

Instead you should use `.Clear();` or `new List<Foo>();`

Based on [this benchmark](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-clear) the fastest way is:

```
FooCollection = new List<Foo>();
```

If you are sure, that you don't need the `FooCollection` again, you can use `FooColleciton = null`. If you want to take care, that the GC give the memory free you can call `GC.Collect();`

[GC Collect Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netcore-3.1)

Here you can find some hints, when it is okay to force the garbage collector:

[When is it acceptable to call GC.Collect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect)

Comment: Why it is faster?

Comment: @GuruStron I have updated my answer. Take a look at the link. There is a benchmark.

Comment: You have added link to benchmark which compares `List.Clear` with `=  new List`. OP just sets list to  `null`

Comment: No to mention necessity of [proper benchmarking](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)