# Can I free the ResourceInteractiveLoader after finish loading in Godot

Tags: c#, godot

I'm building a level management system, which uses the `ResourceInteractiveLoader` to load a level in background.
I have some issue with the memory management, that it seems C# does not allow free specific memory like `delete` and `free()` in C++, and all memory will be handled with GC after unused for a certain elapse, but I want the `ResourceInteractiveLoader` object to be freed on my order, is it possible?

Comment: Did you take a look at the GarbageCollector(GC) class, yet? It allows you to force a garbage collection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-6.0

But keep in mind, that this will bring new performance problems, so only use it, while the player will not notice it.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect

Comment: @Bugfish yes, and that seems not actually a memory free, it only says “do GC now”, but the memory may not meets the criteria for collection

Comment: As I see it ResourceInteractiveLoader implements the IDisposable Interface
https://paulloz.github.io/godot-csharp-api/3.4/Godot.ResourceInteractiveLoader.html
So you can use loader.Dispose() to explicitly release the resources.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-7.0

Comment: @Bugfish oh, thanks, I‘ll try this out. This seems promising.

Comment: Let me know, if it does the trick! 

Will formulate an answer, if it proofs helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ResourceInteractiveLoader implements the IDisposable Interface(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-7.0), which allows you to dispose the loader to explicity release the resources, when you don't need them anymore by calling:

```
loader.Dispose()
```