# How does GC.AddMemoryPressure() know which object to add memory pressure to?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I recently had need to use [GC.AddMemoryPressure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure.aspx) and it struck me as strange that it doesn't accept the object to add memory pressure to as an argument. I assume because it's so closely tied to the runtime, there is some mechanism by which the `this` pointer gets passed to the method. My question is threefold:

1. How does the this pointer get passed to the method?
2. I notice no exception is thrown when calling it from a static method. What happens in this case?
3. Why do other GC methods such as GC.SupressFinalize and GC.ReRegisterForFinalize take an object argument where this method doesn't need one?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not explicitly associated with any specific object. The assumption is that at disposal/finalize time, the same object will remove that pressure. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure.aspx):

> In the simplest usage pattern, a managed object allocates unmanaged memory in the constructor and releases it in the Dispose or Finalize method. Call the AddMemoryPressure method after allocating the unmanaged memory, and call the RemoveMemoryPressure method after releasing it.

In more complicated scenarios, the memory pressure may change over time - but it's still expected to be with the co-operation of the object in question.

Comment: Ah ok, I was assuming this memory pressure was associated with the object that allocates the unmanaged memory, i.e. the GC would prioritise objects with more memory pressure for collection.

Comment: "Call the AddMemoryPressure method after allocating the unmanaged memory". Doesn't it make more sense to call the method before allocation? Otherwise the native/unmanaged code may unnecessarily run out of memory while allocating, because the garbage collector doesn't know about the native/unmanaged code needing memory.

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke: I think if you call it *just before* allocation, that wouldn't give the GC time to collect anyway.

Answer (score 1):

AddMemoryPressure kicks the garbage collector into life sooner than it would do normally. That's all. Suppress and RegisterForFinialise call or not specific code for that type when an instance gets collected and it's finaliser needs to be run...

Suggest you read up on the garbage collector mate, you might find that you didn't need to call IncreaseMemoryPressure, or almost just as likely calling it will cause a deteriation in performance.

Comment: I am allocating large amounts of unmanaged memory, which is tracked using a ConditionalWeakTable. Are you suggesting I don't need to call AddMemoryPressure in this case?

Comment: Nope, that's a good use. Given you call RemoveMemoryPressure correctly. Basically it tells the GC that more memory is being used than it knows about so it needs to get a bit more proactive with the memory it does.