# Why call GC.AddMemoryPressure()?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Why would you ever need to inform the garbage collector about unmanaged memory via `GC.AddMemoryPressure()`? Can't the garbage collector deduce that information itself by looking at the size of the process heap or at the amount of free addresses in the virtual address space or something like that?

Note: this question differs from [What is the point of using GC.AddMemoryPressure with an unmanaged resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149181/what-is-the-point-of-using-gc-addmemorypressure-with-an-unmanaged-resource). That question asks why the information is needed for the GC at all, while this question asks why the GC can't deduce it from process info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the point of using GC.AddMemoryPressure with an unmanaged resource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149181/what-is-the-point-of-using-gc-addmemorypressure-with-an-unmanaged-resource)

Comment: No, my question is different: Can't the garbage collector deduce that itself? While that question asks: why need that info at all?

Comment: How can the GC know how much of the unmanged  process heap is being controlled by each object, by definition .net has no understanding of what is unmanged.    For example we had a system with lots of C++ code, a some .NET object has finalizers that when called allowed the C++ code to free lots of memory.

Comment: PS, I expect most .net programmer will not have a need to use GC.AddMemoryPressure() more then one every 10 years or so......

Comment: "How can the GC know how much of the unmanged process heap is being controlled by each object" And calling GC.AddMemoryPressure() doesn't change that. So the question stands.

Comment: Well of course it does.  The GC cannot possibly discover how much unmanaged memory is used, but of course the programmer knows.  So he tells the GC.

Comment: "How can the GC know how much of the unmanaged process heap is being controlled by each object" You don't pass any object pointer to `AddMemoryPressure()`... So you only inform about the global amount of unmanaged memory. The GC should be able to get that information from the OS just by looking how much of the virtual address space is used, right?

Comment: Optimizations?  Why associate the overhead of trying to factor in unmanaged memory when, as mentioned, this is something that will need to be used very sparingly.  Is even a 2% increase in general GC overhead processing worth it if this only worth consideration 0.01% of the time (and this solution is available for that 0.01% of the time)?