# C# System.AccessviolationException and using GC.Collect

Tags: c#, access-violation

Here is the code sample:

```
ConcurrentCircularBuffer<byte[]> _cList = new ConcurrentCircularBuffer<byte[]>(10);

private Bitmap getBitmap()
{
    byte[] bmpdata = _cList.Dequeue();
    if (bmpdata != null && bmpdata.Length > 0)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bmpdata, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
           
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
            return bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {} 
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }           
    return null;
}

public string GetBase64Image()
{
    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap();
    if (bmp != null)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); // Here I got the System.AccessViolationException
            byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case after few attempts of converting image to base64string I getting the AccessViolationException.

When I'm adding 'GC.Collect()' to my 'Finally' block, the exception doesn't appear.
What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to avoid the using of GC.Collect()?

Source image - is the live-stream from IP-camera, that writes the byte array to implementation of ConcurrentQueue that stores last 10 images.

upd: exception thrown in the multi-thread with low latency between the executions.

upd2:

```
ConcurrentCircularBuffer<byte[]> _cList = new ConcurrentCircularBuffer<byte[]>(10);

public string GetBase64Image()
{
    byte[] bmpdata = _cList.Dequeue();
    if (bmpdata != null && bmpdata.Length > 0)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bmpdata, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
           
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()))
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }             
}
```

At this time is the best solution. Without GC.Collect() - accessviolation when saving bitmap to `MemoryStream`

Comment: You need to debug and find why the AccesViolation exception is raised.  Why are you freeing the handle, in the getBitmap()? the bitmap object is later used by the writeToMS function. I think you need to analyse when and where you use that function. There is no need for your code to forcibly call GC.Collect, and that is unrelated.

Comment: Try dispose image resources: `using Bitmap bmp = getBitmap();`

Comment: Look at [GC.AddMemoryPressure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.addmemorypressure?view=net-6.0) and `GC.RemoveMemoryPressure`. Sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624736/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov doesn't helped

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran the point is the accessviolation thrown by MS. To reproduce the exception: get the byte array from queue, make a bitmap from it and then declare `var ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[bmpdata.Length])` and try to write in that stream. The exception will be thrown. Most frequent when using multithreading. i.e. trying to get base64string in two simultanous threads

Comment: @Rexortis Although MemoryStream has a Dispose method, there is no need to call it, so you don't need the `using`. I guess it only has a Dispose method for symmetry with other stream-type methods.

Comment: handle.Free() is a bug, memory must not be released until the bitmap is disposed.  A better way to do this is by creating the bitmap as normal, call Bitmap.Lock and Marshal.Copy the data.

Comment: Can you use `bmpdata` directly? I.e. `Convert.ToBase64String(_cList.Dequeue());`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Yes, I can. It will solve the problem with saving clean image, but in some cases I need to draw something on bitmap (string or square etc). What to do with that? I think the main reason of the exception is too fast using of `MemoryStream`. `GC` can't collect the garbage in time and `new MemoryStream()` tries to write to the allocated memory for previuous `MemoryStream`. When I use `Thread.Sleep(500)` the exception doesn't rise.