# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. exception while generatinf pdf of gridview using Itextsharper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, memory, out

Hi I am getting an error of OOM while generating pdf from gridview data. Its working fine for 40k records but after that error is generating. My script is as

```
CreditInvoiceViewModel obj = new CreditInvoiceViewModel();
ResolveKeys(obj);
obj.PrepareForExcelInView(sno);
GridView gvReport = new GridView();
gvReport.AllowPaging = false;
gvReport.DataSource = obj.xresultDataset.Tables[0];
gvReport.DataBind();

string attachment = "attachment; filename=Employee.pdf";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
gvReport.RenderControl(htextw);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
document.Open();
StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlworker.Parse(str);
document.Close();
Response.Write(document);
Response.End();
```

I am getting dt in less than 1 mint for more than one 100,000 records but the only line "  htmlworker.Parse(str);" is culprit. I have also tried AddCell(ph) methods but gives even poor result than upper code. Even tried sql2pdf Stored procedure but all fails for huge data. 
     I have to print about 200,000 records as invoice with 9-10 columns.I am using Window 7,sqlserver 2008,visual studio 2010,.net framework 4.5. Have done so much r&d. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance. I can't change any RAM or server so please suggest only code specific changes.

Comment: Did you tried any memory profiler to see where does the memory really leaked? Nothing apparent from code posted.

Comment: Assuming that this code (and the resto of it that you do not showed) do not have problem os "memory leaks" (like references that never disappear), it's possible that this is not a question of "memory leak", but instead, a question of the GC not recovering memory fast enough?

Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233596/best-practice-for-forcing-garbage-collection-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have not tried any memory profiler as not much aware of that. I was thinking its because of large data pdf. How and where can I use GC in single call of a funtion as pdf is to be created in single call.

Comment: If a single record processing (generating a single PDF) is enough to cause a OOM, then there is no solution if the problem is with some of the libraries you are using. If the problem is the "number" of reocrds processed, you can call the Collector by calling System.GC.Collect(). This not good practice, anyway. You can try to find WHICH object is the culprit for the memory consumption and use it inside a "usin" statement. But the object must implement IDisposable.