# How to rename an instantiated array object in C Sharp

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, rename

My goal is to **rename** an **instantiated array**.

Below is a test case. The actual program I have reads data from an excel spread sheet, performs filtering and type conversion, and then stores that data in an array (e.g. the `allData` array below).

Once the data is stored in the array I need to split the array into two copies of itself and perform a set of separate tasks on each of those copies.

To achieve this I created a **clone** (in the example `arr1`). Now I have two copies of the same data (`allData` and `arr1`) but the term `allData`, that was **appropriately named in the past code**, now feels inappropriately named, so I would like to rename it.

I considered creating another clone, but that would just leave the array (`allData`) sitting there unused and needlessly taking up memory.

I also considered `arr2 = allData` but that just leaves a reference (allData) sitting there needlessly. What I really want is to rename allData to arr2.

```
namespace nspace
{
    public class c
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

        object[][] allData = new object[10][];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
                {
                        // fill array with something
                }
        }

        arr1 = allData.clone();
        // Rename array allData to arr2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually `arr2 = allData` this is OK, only the reference is copied, dont give yourself a headache it will save a ton of time

Comment: Why not make it object[][][]allDataInstances = new object[2][][]

Comment: Totally appreciate the suggestions Sherlock and user3488765. I agree there are solutions that will save a great deal of time but for educational purposes I would like to know how to rename an instantiated array. Appreciate any help you could give.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the excel data in a separate method, then write the values into two arrays that you pass by reference. By setting the scope of **all_data** to this method only, as soon as it is exited the array will be deleted on the next garbage collector call. You can find more information here: [How to delete an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584017/how-to-delete-an-array-in-c). Something along these lines:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object[][] arr1 = new object[10][];
        object[][] arr2 = new object[10][];
        GetData(ref arr1, ref arr2);
    }
    private static void GetData(ref object[][] arr1, ref object[][] arr2)
    {
        object[][] allData = new object[10][];
        object[] data;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //this is just for sample purposes
        {
            data = new object[10];
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { data[j] = i * j; }
            allData[i] = data;
        }

        arr1 = allData;
        arr2 = allData;
    }
```