# What will be better way to clear Array in concern of Memory

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management

**** EDIT *****

There is a question - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584017/how-to-delete-an-array-in-c) , I have gone through. My Purpose of asking is different (as in that question, asker is asking for solution(s) which he got. and here I'm looking for better way to accomplish the task (I know two solutions and asking better one or even better 3rd option))

---

I have an array of `Obj` .
I know these two ways which are clearing (or doing similar) an Array.

`int length = arrayOfObj.Length`

1:
`arrayOfObj = new Obj[length]`

2:
`Array.Clear(arrayOfObj, 0, length)`

they both are apparently doing the same thing.
But which one of this is better in terms of Memory.
Or I should leave this matter of Internal Garbage collection ?

Comment: Leave it to the GC as long as they don´t implement `IDisposable` in which case you should dispose every single element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an array in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584017/how-to-delete-an-array-in-c)

Comment: Also, if `IDisposable` is implemented, use a `using` block to manage disposal.

Comment: @HimBromBeere So If I Make `Obj` implementing `IDisposable` what optimisation I can do? Should I iterate through array and dispose every object? and Out of curiosity(not related to this question), Disposing an object is better or using `using (Obj) {}` ?

Comment: For example `List<T>` uses `Array.Clear()` in background when executing `List<T>.Clear()` method.

Comment: When your instances implement `IDisposable` you *have to* call `Dispoase` in any way as you´re producing memory-leaks otherwise. But I propse to use `using (var instance = new ...)` which automatically calls `Dispose` even in case of an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to worry about it.  As you suggested, garbage collection will take care of it for you.  However, if you still have references elsewhere to any of the objects that were in your array, those objects, of course, won't be garbage collected.

I should also mention something about `IDisposable` as suggested by the comments under your question.  The .NET framework's garbage collector will release *managed* resources when appropriate.  The purpose of the `IDisposable` interface is to guarantee that *unmanaged* resources get released, such as open files and streams.  If the class whose objects are in your array have any such unmanaged resources, the class should implement `IDisposable` and you should call `Dispose` on every object before you clear the array.

Normally when dealing with `IDisposable`, you would utilize the `using` statement to guarantee that the object was properly disposed when you're done with it.  However, since you are dealing with a *collection* of disposable objects in this case, it's unlikely each object was created inside a `using` statement (it could be possible in some extravagant scenario).  Therefore, you must loop through the elements and call `Dispose` on each one before you clear the array**.  This, again, is only if the objects in your collection have unmanaged resources that need to be dealt with before each object is garbage collected.

** Keep in mind: you'll run into trouble if you have external references to any of those objects and try to use them again afterward since they will have already been disposed.

Comment: `The Joy of CLR` or `How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Managed Code`

Comment: @Equalsk The CLR is indeed "the bomb" ;)

Comment: @rory.ap  Yes I got that. Thank you. BTW are there any additional benefits of using `Dispose` ? (see in question's comments)

Comment: @AmitMaheshwari -- I was working on that.  See my update.

Comment: @rory.ap That's what I was looking for. Marking it as an answer. Thank you.