# open office word 2013 through C# interop is very slow

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I tried to open a document through c# interop interface, but below code take 2 to 4 seconds to complete.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

excel just takes 600ms to run this code Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

but msword need 2-4s still

the same program run at windows 7 + office 2010 is super fast, but run at windows 10 + office 2013 is not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug slow Office application interop constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310221/how-to-debug-slow-office-application-interop-constructor)

Comment: not working, excel just takes 600ms to run this code Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); but word need 2-4s still

Comment: Any number of factors could be influencing how fast (or slow) an Office application starts. Did you compare the time it takes to start the same application, on the same system, as an end-user? Excel could be loading fewer add-ins than Word, for example... And Excel won't load a workbook when it's started using the interop, Word will load a new document.