# Objects ready for finalization are being blocked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks

Whenever someone tries to access my application, if more than one person is using it it starts to hang.  I recreated the issue and ran DebugDiag memory check and get this warning.

```
Number of objects ready for finalization: 457779
```

It then tells me that the finalizer thread may be blocked.

```
As the number of finalizable objects is more than 0, please check the finalizer thread to see if it is blocked or active

Finalizer Thread
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+14
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+8f
clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+17c
clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+113
clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+7c
clr!FinalizerThread::WaitForFinalizerEvent+44
clr!FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadWorker+54
clr!Frame::Push+59
clr!FillInRegTypeMap+198
clr!FillInRegTypeMap+c1
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]
clr!FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadStart+10a
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+86
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+14
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Are multiple users accessing the same objects held in memory...? You may need some locks

Comment: Do many of your types have finalizers? If so what are you doing in the finalizers? The stack above just shows that the thread is waiting. It isn't necessarily blocked.

Comment: Your finalizer thread looks fine, but that's a lot of finalizable objects, especially for a web application. Are you disposing everything properly? To investigate a hang, debugdiag isn't the best tool. Try attaching the Visual studio debugger and look at the "parallel stacks" window

Comment: There are areas in the application where `GC.Collect()` is being used as well as Close/Dispose.

Comment: Why are you calling GC.Collect() directly?  That's almost always a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118633/whats-so-wrong-about-using-gc-collect)

Comment: Added another error I found.  Removed GC.Collect

Comment: If you used DebugDiag, I assume you have a memory dump? If so, remember that you can open it directly in Visual Studio, then check the "Parallel Stacks" window I mentioned earlier